# memory allocation of a pseudo-generic nested array

Tags: c, dictionary, generics

```
(*((_SINGARR) _receptive->__m2dimensio + g_curr++)) = (_SINGARR) malloc(sizeof(*((_SINGARR)(_generic)) * g));
```

the aforementioned produces the following compiler warning
"assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast "

I suppose it's somehow procured by the `sizeof` operator evaluation of the typecasted dereferenced void* or am I just not dereferencing accordingly?

`_generic` is a `void*` method parameter

`_receptive` - `typedef struct*` method parameter used in the accessing of its 2D-array property (also pseudo-generic)

expanded directives

`_SINGARR char*`

Comment: Carefully examine the type of the expression on the left side of `=` and on the right side of it.

Comment: `malloc()` returns a pointer. You're assigning that to the location you get by dereferencing a `char*` pointer.

Comment: please post something that can be compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you expand all the stuff, it looks like

```
* (char*) p = (char*) malloc(...);
```

This means, there is a pointer on the right side `(char*)` and a character (`*(char*)`, integer type) on the left side.

Now the warning message becomes clearer:

> assignment makes integer (*the part on the left side of the assignment*) from pointer (*the part on the right side of the assignment*) without a cast

---

Unrelated, but expanding the `sizeof(...)` part will become `sizeof(*((char*)(_generic)) * g)`, which in turn is `sizeof(<some character value> * g)`, which in turn will become `sizeof(<some integer value>)`, which is `sizeof(int)` and finally becomes 4 or 8 bytes depending on the architecture of your machine.

Comment: Hence the compilation warning is a fallout to inaccurate lvalue dereferencing? And if so, precisely how should be the left expression re-formulated for such a warning to be omitted?

Comment: @deftartisan Well, don't de-reference the pointer on the left side. Assigning a pointer to a pointer won't trigger this warning.